# angular.factory is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory and I have the error in the title. How can I fix this?

```
(function (angular,namespace) {

    var marketplace = namespace.require('private.marketplace');

    angular.factory('blueStripeViewModelFactory', [
        '$http', function blueStripeViewModelFactory($http) {
            return new BlueStripeViewModel("id", 10);
        }
    ]);

    marketplace.blueStripeViewModelFactory = blueStripeViewModelFactory;

})(window.angular,window.namespace);
```

Comment: Create an angular `module` and then create factory inside that module.

Comment: You should to use `angular.module(...).factory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an independent factory as it should be created within a module.

**Example,**

```
angular.module("myFactoryModule").factory("blueStripeViewModelFactory",function(){
    // define your factory
});
```

Now you are able to use this factory in any of your module. To use this module, you just need to add an injector of your factory module (here, `myFactoryModule`).

Example,

```
angular.module("anotherModule", ["myFactoryModule"]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful